# How can I validate that total span of dates adds up to 3 years in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

In my Rails App, I have a `bill_payer` who `has_many` addresses (to represent his address history). I have created a dynamic nested form which contains all the fields which is working fine. On the address model there is a `move_in_date` attribute. Ideally the bill_payer should fill his address(es) so I have a record of where they've lived for the past three years.

However I need to validate that all the dates for each address supplied do indeed give me 3 years of history to the current day and I'm a bit stuck.

If it was just one address and date, it's easy, since elsewhere I'm using the validates_timeliness gem:

`validates_date :move_in_date, :before => lambda { 3.years.ago }`

But I'm dealing with properties over a set of models here so I don't think this simple approach can work.

Any help would be great!

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you properly but [custom validators](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators) aren't any help?

Comment: Why not use a method in BillPayer that checks each collects each address you give it and add up the dates?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like a job for a validator on the address model, as each address can be valid individually, while it is the complete set that either does or does not meet the condition.

So you do not want to prevent the addresses being saved, rather you want to point out that a condition has not been met.

You might simply check the value of the minimum move_in date for a bill_payer's addresses and compare that to 3.years.ago, and prompt for more addresses to be added if that condition is not met.

Answer (score 0):

Took some time (admittedly I worked on another project), but I eventually solved this by adding a custom validation method on the `bill_payer` model:

```
validate :address_history


def address_history
     if self.addresses.size < 3 
        time_period = 0
        self.addresses.each do |address|
            time_period = time_period + (Time.now.to_i - address.move_in_date.to_time.to_i)
        end
             if (time_period) < (Time.now.to_i - 3.years.ago.to_time.to_i)
                errors.add(:move_in_date, "You must provide 3 years of address history")
            end
    end
end
```

Possibly a bit clunky, but essentially this adds up all the dates and converts them to integers. If they add up to less then the integer given for 3 years ago, I flag a validation error.

Also, there was a slight change in requirement meaning if 3 valid addresses were given, I don't need to check the history.